# perl how to read files one by one from directory other than array concept?

Tags: perl, file-io

How can I read a log files one by one from directory other than array concept. I tried with that concept but I didn't met requirements. Because in current working directory log files keep on adding to it. If i use array concept there are missing of latest log files. Is there any better solution for this? Below code what I have tried, here array contents all files of a directory.

```
opendir ( DIR, $readDir ) || die "Error in opening dir $readDir\n";
my @files = grep { !/^\.\.?$/ } readdir DIR;
print STDERR "files: @files \n\n";
```

Comment: Why not use the iterator instead? `while (my $file = readdir DIR)`

Comment: Are you saying you need a way to get a list of files in a directory but want them given to you one at a time, rather than slurping up the entire array at once?  Look at the File::Next module which does exactly that.

Comment: @AndyLester Since you're the author of that module, how does using it differ from using the iterating solution I suggested above?

Comment: If all he's doing is reading a single directory, then the `while` over `readdir` will do just fine, so long as he excludes `.` and `..` and any directories.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using linux,

```
my $log_content = `cat /log/dir/*.log`;
```

This will combine all the log file contents as one.

Comment: @sabuj I am using windows. More over i don't want to combine all log files, but need to process all the files individually.